# Is the use of hidden fields in forms insecure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hidden-field

For example
Imagine I have the following form

```
  <%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id%>
    <%= f.hidden_field :article_id%>

    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>

    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

I got the :user_id and :article_id values with:

```
Comment.new(:user_id => current_user.id, :article_id => @article.id)
```

When I display the form in the browser it will look like this:

```
<form action="/comments" method="post">

  <input some_rails_tokens_here />

  <!-- THIS AREA HERE-->
  <input id="comment_user_id" name="comment[user_id]" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <input id="comment_article_id" name="comment[article_id]" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <!-- THIS AREA HERE-->

  <label for="comment_content">Content</label><br />
  <textarea id="comment_content" name="comment[content]"></textarea>

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

My question is, what if someone changes the post parameters and instead of being
the value for :user_id => 1 it is changed to :user_id => 2. The same with the article.

I want to believe that is verified with the rails tokens, but I am not sure.

Comment: It was very easy to change the values. In "firebug" -> "edit" option, I just changed the "value" in HTML and voila! instead of being the user 1 I was posting as user 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A hidden field in a form *is no more or less secure than any other data that come from user*. That is, **it should *not* be trivally trusted**: It *comes* from the user and is open to manipulation and specialty injection.

When the data is sent back to the server, the server *should* validate *that data* and not assume that the operation is allowed/invalid just based on a particular user-modifiable context. Depending upon needs, approaches like hash checksums can be used to have a very high degree of confidence that the data was not tampered with (but again, this *should* be verified by the server each request!). Using "session state" mitigates the problem entirely by keeping the data out of user-manipulation land.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

If comments from un-registered users are allowed then why bother about the user_id at all, and if comments are only allowed from registered users then use [sessions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) to track the user, instead of passing user_id in a form element.

And to answer your question if using hidden fields is insecure, without proper sanity check even the visible fields are insecure.

Answer (score 1):

If the value of those fields is critical, then don't trust the user to return them unchanged. Otherwise, a hidden field is no less or no more secure than a regular visible field - if it's in the HTML, someone can change it.

Answer (score 1):

Data sent from the client to the server cannot be trusted without server-side checks (including HTML forms and browser cookies). The data could be maliciously modified or sent multiple times.

I have read stories about e-commerce sites that submitted the product price from an HTML form. A cheap user could edit the HTML form data they submit to the server to change the product price.